# CSS cache bust for image

Tags: html, css

I know that if I use some query parameter when adding css to html, it will prevent using cached css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css?version=1.0.0">
```

But considering that I have an image referenced  inside this css:

```
mystyle.css:
#site_logo {
    background-image:url(../img/logo.png);
}
```

When I update only the image and deploy css with a new version (no changes in css code), will it bust the cache for image too? (renew logo.png)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css?version=1.0.1">
```

Comment: Why not try it and then you'll have your answer? :-) Given it's a completely different name of the file, it'll not be cached if your CSS version is incremented otherwise you can use the same technique on your image within css.

Comment: @Morpheus this question covers busting the url of image inside css, not url of importing the css file

Comment: @Adriani6 trying at localhost doesn't happen to be a good test. Thanks for answer :)

Comment: But in this case the image name will not change, including the image url will not change, just the css url that would change. The bust will work for the image?

Answer (score 0):

Request for assets embedded in CSS file are done separate server calls so if address for those additional resources did not change to the previous version it will try to use cached version that is if there are no other cache boosting mechanisms involved.
You can try read about [service workers](https://developers.google.com/web/showcase/2015/service-workers-iowa) for example.